# Finding surface fit on 3D graph that have different data length

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I have a question to find the surface plot on the list of data with different data length.  Each of the sample a different length, how can I combine all these data and find the best fit surface for the 3D graph plot? Appreciate the advice. Thank you.

```
Prange = {{-0.1, 0.7}, {0, 32}, {0, 20}}

Dimensions5cmMean ={{0, 5, 10.0283}, {1/5, 5, 10.4103}, {2/5, 5, 8.66286}, {3/5, 5, 7.34104}}

G5 = ListPointPlot3D[Dimensions5cmMean, PlotRange -> Prange, 
  AxesLabel -> {"ε", "L", "KΩ/cm"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Pink]

Dimensions7cmMean ={{0, 7, 11.425}, {1/7, 7, 11.3625}, {2/7, 7, 10.4944}, {3/7, 7, 9.76909}, {4/7, 7, 9.08636}}


G7 = ListPointPlot3D[Dimensions7cmMean, PlotRange -> Prange, 
  AxesLabel -> {"ε", "L", "KΩ/cm"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Purple]

Dimensions10cmMean ={{0, 10, 12.8775}, {1/10, 10, 14.2447}, {1/5, 10, 12.9257}, {3/10, 10,11.984}, {2/5, 10, 11.2065}, {1/2, 10, 10.5361}, {3/5, 10, 9.87188}}

G10 = ListPointPlot3D[Dimensions10cmMean, PlotRange -> Prange, 
  AxesLabel -> {"ε", "L", "KΩ/cm"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Green]

Dimensions20cmMean ={{0, 20, 14.7506}, {1/20, 20, 16.2232}, {1/10, 20, 15.504}, {3/20, 20, 14.6201}, {1/5, 20, 13.9161}, {1/4, 20, 13.266}, {3/10, 20, 12.7178}, {7/20, 20, 12.2796}, {2/5, 20, 11.8446}, {9/20, 20, 11.4573}, {1/2, 20, 11.0733}, {11/20, 20, 10.7722}, {3/5, 20,10.4332}} 

G20 = ListPointPlot3D[Dimensions20cmMean, PlotRange -> Prange, 
  AxesLabel -> {"ε", "L", "KΩ/cm"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Orange]

Dimensions27cmMean ={{0, 27, 16.8722}, {1/27, 27, 18.2381}, {2/27, 27, 17.2052}, {1/9, 27,16.4461}, {4/27, 27, 15.95}, {5/27, 27, 15.4401}, {2/9, 27,15.0268}, {7/27, 27, 14.5422}, {8/27, 27, 14.19}, {1/3, 27,13.9292}, {10/27, 27, 13.5257}, {11/27, 27, 13.2465}, {4/9, 27, 12.9662}, {13/27, 27, 12.7288}, {14/27, 27, 12.5179}, {5/9, 27, 12.275}, {16/27, 27, 12.0376}}

G27 = ListPointPlot3D[Dimensions27cmMean, PlotRange -> Prange, 
  AxesLabel -> {"ε", "L", "KΩ/cm"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue]

Dimensions30cmMean ={{0, 30, 12.5678}, {1/30, 30, 16.6086}, {1/15, 30, 16.7578}, {1/10, 30, 16.3722}, {2/15, 30, 15.7368}, {1/6, 30, 15.0586}, {1/5, 30, 14.4477}, {7/30, 30, 13.8928}, {4/15, 30, 13.3904}, {3/10, 30, 12.9197}, {1/3, 30, 12.4946}, {11/30, 30, 12.0886}, {2/5, 30, 11.7595}, {13/30, 30, 11.4233}, {7/15, 30, 11.1133}, {1/2, 30, 10.833}, {8/15, 30, 10.6007}, {17/30, 30, 10.3411}, {3/5, 30, 10.1111}}

G30 = ListPointPlot3D[Dimensions30cmMean, PlotRange -> Prange, 
  AxesLabel -> {"ε", "L", "KΩ/cm"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]

Show[{G5, G7, G10, G20, G27, G30}]
```

Comment: why not `ListPlot3D[
 Join[Dimensions5cmMean, Dimensions7cmMean, Dimensions10cmMean, 
  Dimensions20cmMean, Dimensions27cmMean, Dimensions30cmMean]]`?

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of points is very limited for some of your lists,
it seems that the only reasonable solution would be to interpolate your findings with a limited `InterpolationOrder` parameter. by default, if the points are not arranged in a regular grid, this parameter is set to one.

Here's the code:

```
int = Interpolation[
  Join[Dimensions5cmMean, Dimensions7cmMean, Dimensions10cmMean, 
   Dimensions20cmMean, Dimensions27cmMean, Dimensions30cmMean]]

Show[Join[Dimensions5cmMean, Dimensions7cmMean, Dimensions10cmMean, 
   Dimensions20cmMean, Dimensions27cmMean, Dimensions30cmMean] // 
  ListPointPlot3D[#, 
    AxesLabel -> {"\[CurlyEpsilon]", "L", "K\[CapitalOmega]/cm"}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> Prange
    ] &,
 Plot3D[int[x, y], {x, 0, 0.6}, {y, 5, 30}]]
```

[image]

Now, if you had more points, it should be possible to interpolate each list and than smooth your data (but I would not feel very comfortamble with interpolating 4 points to get a meaningful result).

**Edit**

Here's a small function which uses interpolation on separate lists to get a regular grid of points.

```
prepareDataForInterpolation[data_, numberOfPoints_, 
  interpolationOrder_] := 
 Module[{len, finalData = data, interpolatedData, 
   interpolation = 
    Interpolation[#, (InterpolationOrder -> {interpolationOrder, 
         0})] &, xMin, xMax, y},
  len = Length[data];
  interpolatedData = Map[interpolation[data[[#]]] &, Range[len]];

  xMin = Max[interpolatedData[[;; , 1, 1, 1]]];
  xMax = Min[interpolatedData[[;; , 1, 1, 2]]];
  y = interpolatedData[[;; , 1, 2, 1]];

  finalData = Table[
    Table[{x, y[[i]], interpolatedData[[i]][x, y[[i]]]}, {x, xMin, 
      xMax, (xMax - xMin)/numberOfPoints}],
    {i, len}];
  Return[finalData]

]


data = {Dimensions5cmMean, Dimensions7cmMean, Dimensions10cmMean, 
Dimensions20cmMean, Dimensions27cmMean, Dimensions30cmMean};
newSet = prepareDataForInterpolation[data, 5, 2];
int = Interpolation[Join @@ newSet, InterpolationOrder -> {2, 1}];
Show[newSet // 
  ListPointPlot3D[#, 
    AxesLabel -> {"\[CurlyEpsilon]", "L", "K\[CapitalOmega]/cm"}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> Prange
    ] &,
 Plot3D[int[x, y], {x, 0, 0.6}, {y, 5, 30}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Should be also possible to interpolate the relation in ys (provided the data is smooth). Should be easy to do it but have to go!