# Surface fit in Mathematica for sigmoid type of surface

Tags: fitting

```
k1 = {0.01, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 
   800, 1*^3, 2*^3, 4*^3, 5*^3, 10*^3, 15*^3, 20*^3, 30*^3, 40*^3, 
   70*^3, 1*^5, 1*^6, 1*^8, 1*^12};
k2 = k1;
z={{3.14183, 3.15372, 3.16557, 3.1888, 3.21143, 3.2335, 3.25502, 
  3.40161, 3.60178, 3.89912, 4.27784, 4.51097, 4.66712, 4.77748, 
  4.8587, 4.9688, 5.039, 5.18595, 5.26072, 5.27562, 5.30527, 5.3151, 
  5.32001, 5.3249, 5.32735, 5.33048, 5.33174, 5.33437, 5.33466, 
  5.33466}, {3.15372, 3.16551, 3.17725, 3.20027, 3.22271, 3.24459, 
  3.26595, 3.41148, 3.61051, 3.90663, 4.28437, 4.51712, 4.67308, 
  4.78331, 4.86444, 4.97441, 5.04452, 5.19122, 5.26585, 5.28072, 
  5.3103, 5.32011, 5.325, 5.32989, 5.33232, 5.33546, 5.33671, 5.33933,
   5.33962, 5.33962}, {3.16557, 3.17725, 3.18888, 3.21171, 3.23396, 
  3.25566, 3.27685, 3.42134, 3.61925, 3.91416, 4.29093, 4.5233, 
  4.67906, 4.78917, 4.87021, 4.98005, 5.05006, 5.19654, 5.27102, 
  5.28585, 5.31537, 5.32516, 5.33004, 5.33491, 5.33734, 5.34046, 
  5.34171, 5.34433, 5.34462, 5.34462}, {3.1888, 3.20027, 3.21171, 
  3.23415, 3.25604, 3.2774, 3.29825, 3.44075, 3.63648, 3.92904, 
  4.30394, 4.53557, 4.69095, 4.80082, 4.88168, 4.99127, 5.0611, 
  5.20712, 5.2813, 5.29607, 5.32546, 5.3352, 5.34006, 5.34491, 
  5.34733, 5.35043, 5.35168, 5.35428, 5.35457, 5.35457}, {3.21143, 
  3.22271, 3.23396, 3.25604, 3.27758, 3.29861, 3.31916, 3.45976, 
  3.6534, 3.94371, 4.31679, 4.54772, 4.70273, 4.81237, 4.89307, 
  5.00241, 5.07207, 5.21763, 5.29153, 5.30624, 5.33549, 5.34519, 
  5.35002, 5.35485, 5.35726, 5.36035, 5.36159, 5.36418, 5.36446, 
  5.36447}, {3.2335, 3.24459, 3.25566, 3.2774, 3.29861, 3.31934, 
  3.33959, 3.47838, 3.67002, 3.95816, 4.3295, 4.55974, 4.71441, 
  4.82382, 4.90436, 5.01346, 5.08295, 5.22808, 5.30169, 5.31634, 
  5.34547, 5.35512, 5.35993, 5.36473, 5.36713, 5.37021, 5.37144, 
  5.37402, 5.3743, 5.37431}, {3.25502, 3.26595, 3.27685, 3.29825, 
  3.31916, 3.33959, 3.35957, 3.49663, 3.68636, 3.9724, 4.34206, 
  4.57165, 4.72598, 4.83518, 4.91556, 5.02444, 5.09377, 5.23846, 
  5.3118, 5.32638, 5.35539, 5.36499, 5.36978, 5.37456, 5.37695, 
  5.38001, 5.38124, 5.3838, 5.38409, 5.38409}, {3.40161, 3.41148, 
  3.42134, 3.44075, 3.45976, 3.47838, 3.49663, 3.62294, 3.80053, 
  4.07313, 4.43191, 4.65739, 4.80966, 4.91755, 4.99695, 5.10437, 
  5.1726, 5.31436, 5.38575, 5.39991, 5.42802, 5.43731, 5.44195, 
  5.44657, 5.44887, 5.45184, 5.45302, 5.4555, 5.45577, 
  5.45578}, {3.60178, 3.61051, 3.61925, 3.63648, 3.6534, 3.67002, 
  3.68636, 3.80053, 3.96402, 4.22067, 4.56676, 4.78784, 4.93811, 
  5.04477, 5.12321, 5.22903, 5.29595, 5.43379, 5.50244, 5.51598, 
  5.54279, 5.55163, 5.55603, 5.56042, 5.56261, 5.56542, 5.56655, 
  5.5689, 5.56916, 5.56916}, {3.89912, 3.90663, 3.91416, 3.92904, 
  3.94371, 3.95816, 3.9724, 4.07313, 4.22067, 4.45929, 4.79267, 
  5.01129, 5.16153, 5.26841, 5.34684, 5.45194, 5.5177, 5.65057, 
  5.71509, 5.72767, 5.75243, 5.76056, 5.7646, 5.76862, 5.77062, 
  5.77319, 5.77422, 5.77637, 5.7766, 5.77661}, {4.27784, 4.28437, 
  4.29093, 4.30394, 4.31679, 4.32949, 4.34205, 4.43191, 4.56676, 
  4.79267, 5.12427, 5.35154, 5.51133, 5.62583, 5.70959, 5.82025, 
  5.88786, 6.01851, 6.07839, 6.08977, 6.11187, 6.11904, 6.12259, 
  6.12611, 6.12786, 6.13011, 6.131, 6.13287, 6.13308, 
  6.13308}, {4.51096, 4.51711, 4.5233, 4.53556, 4.54771, 4.55974, 
  4.57165, 4.65738, 4.78783, 5.01129, 5.35153, 5.59457, 5.77061, 
  5.89882, 5.99297, 6.11627, 6.1899, 6.3254, 6.38356, 6.3943, 6.41487,
   6.42146, 6.42471, 6.42792, 6.42952, 6.43155, 6.43237, 6.43406, 
  6.43425, 6.43425}, {4.66712, 4.67307, 4.67906, 4.69095, 4.70273, 
  4.71441, 4.72598, 4.80965, 4.93811, 5.16152, 5.51133, 5.77061, 
  5.96487, 6.11006, 6.21824, 6.36019, 6.44356, 6.58959, 6.64793, 
  6.65837, 6.67808, 6.68431, 6.68737, 6.69039, 6.69188, 6.69378, 
  6.69454, 6.69612, 6.6963, 6.6963}, {4.77747, 4.7833, 4.78916, 
  4.80081, 4.81236, 4.82382, 4.83518, 4.91754, 5.04476, 5.2684, 
  5.62583, 5.89882, 6.11005, 6.27288, 6.39718, 6.56288, 6.65977, 
  6.82185, 6.88182, 6.8922, 6.9115, 6.91753, 6.92046, 6.92335, 
  6.92478, 6.9266, 6.92732, 6.92883, 6.92899, 6.92899}, {4.8587, 
  4.86443, 4.87021, 4.88168, 4.89306, 4.90435, 4.91556, 4.99695, 
  5.12321, 5.34683, 5.70958, 5.99297, 6.21824, 6.39718, 6.53781, 
  6.73082, 6.84499, 7.02906, 7.09193, 7.10244, 7.12166, 7.12758, 
  7.13045, 7.13326, 7.13465, 7.13641, 7.13711, 7.13857, 7.13873, 
  7.13873}, {4.9688, 4.9744, 4.98004, 4.99126, 5.0024, 5.01346, 
  5.02443, 5.10436, 5.22903, 5.45193, 5.82025, 6.11627, 6.36018, 
  6.56288, 6.73081, 6.97944, 7.13719, 7.38552, 7.45793, 7.46913, 
  7.48895, 7.49488, 7.49772, 7.5005, 7.50186, 7.50358, 7.50426, 
  7.50568, 7.50583, 7.50584}, {5.039, 5.04451, 5.05006, 5.0611, 
  5.07206, 5.08295, 5.09376, 5.17259, 5.29594, 5.51769, 5.88785, 
  6.18989, 6.44356, 6.65977, 6.84499, 7.13719, 7.34094, 7.68224, 
  7.76976, 7.78219, 7.80341, 7.80957, 7.8125, 7.81534, 7.81672, 
  7.81847, 7.81915, 7.82058, 7.82074, 7.82074}, {5.18594, 5.19122, 
  5.19653, 5.20711, 5.21762, 5.22807, 5.23845, 5.31435, 5.43379, 
  5.65056, 6.0185, 6.32539, 6.58958, 6.82184, 7.02905, 7.38552, 
  7.68223, 8.55198, 8.85827, 8.88692, 8.92709, 8.93697, 8.94142, 
  8.94558, 8.94757, 8.95003, 8.95098, 8.95294, 8.95315, 
  8.95316}, {5.26071, 5.26584, 5.27101, 5.28129, 5.29152, 5.30169, 
  5.31179, 5.38575, 5.50243, 5.71508, 6.07838, 6.38355, 6.64792, 
  6.88181, 7.09192, 7.45793, 7.76976, 8.85827, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477}, {5.27561, 5.28071, 5.28584, 5.29607, 
  5.30623, 5.31633, 5.32638, 5.3999, 5.51597, 5.72766, 6.08976, 
  6.39429, 6.65836, 6.89219, 7.10243, 7.46912, 7.78218, 8.88691, 
  9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477}, {5.30527, 5.3103, 
  5.31536, 5.32545, 5.33549, 5.34546, 5.35538, 5.42801, 5.54278, 
  5.75242, 6.11186, 6.41486, 6.67807, 6.91149, 7.12165, 7.48894, 
  7.80341, 8.92709, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477}, {5.3151, 5.3201, 5.32515, 5.33519, 5.34518, 5.35511, 
  5.36498, 5.43731, 5.55162, 5.76055, 6.11903, 6.42145, 6.68431, 
  6.91752, 7.12757, 7.49487, 7.80957, 8.93696, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477}, {5.32, 5.325, 5.33003, 5.34005, 5.35001,
   5.35992, 5.36977, 5.44194, 5.55602, 5.76459, 6.12258, 6.4247, 
  6.68736, 6.92046, 7.13044, 7.49772, 7.81249, 8.94142, 9.42477, 
  9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477}, {5.32489, 5.32988, 5.3349, 
  5.3449, 5.35484, 5.36472, 5.37455, 5.44656, 5.56041, 5.76861, 
  6.1261, 6.42791, 6.69038, 6.92335, 7.13325, 7.50049, 7.81533, 
  8.94558, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477}, {5.32734, 
  5.33232, 5.33733, 5.34732, 5.35725, 5.36712, 5.37694, 5.44887, 
  5.5626, 5.77061, 6.12785, 6.42951, 6.69187, 6.92477, 7.13464, 
  7.50185, 7.81671, 8.94756, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477}, {5.33048, 5.33545, 5.34045, 5.35043, 5.36034, 5.3702, 
  5.38, 5.45183, 5.56541, 5.77318, 6.1301, 6.43155, 6.69378, 6.92659, 
  7.13641, 7.50357, 7.81846, 8.95002, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477, 9.42477}, {5.33173, 5.3367, 5.3417, 5.35167, 5.36158, 
  5.37143, 5.38123, 5.45301, 5.56654, 5.77421, 6.13099, 6.43236, 
  6.69453, 6.92731, 7.13711, 7.50425, 7.81915, 8.95098, 9.42477, 
  9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477}, {5.33436, 5.33932, 5.34432, 
  5.35428, 5.36417, 5.37401, 5.3838, 5.45549, 5.56889, 5.77636, 
  6.13286, 6.43405, 6.69611, 6.92882, 7.13856, 7.50567, 7.82057, 
  8.95294, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477}, {5.33465, 
  5.33961, 5.34461, 5.35456, 5.36446, 5.3743, 5.38408, 5.45577, 
  5.56915, 5.77659, 6.13307, 6.43424, 6.69629, 6.92898, 7.13872, 
  7.50582, 7.82073, 8.95315, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477}, {5.33465, 5.33962, 5.34461, 5.35456, 5.36446, 5.3743, 
  5.38408, 5.45577, 5.56915, 5.7766, 6.13307, 6.43424, 6.69629, 
  6.92899, 7.13872, 7.50583, 7.82073, 8.95315, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477, 
  9.42477, 9.42477, 9.42477}};
z1 = ArrayReshape[z, {Length[k1], Length[k2]}];
ListPlot3D[z1, Mesh -> Full, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors"]
plane = Fit[data, {1, x, y}, {x, y}]
Show[Plot3D[plane, {x, 0, 1*^12}, {y, 0, 1*^12}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
  PlotRange -> {0, 2}], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.05], Map[Point, data]}]]
```

I have a surface plot and I wanted to fit an equation which captures this surface. Since the surface is abnormal, I think we cannot use the equation of plane to fit the surface. Does *Mathematica* offer any functions for this so I can directly use it?

The surface looks like a sigmoid function in two dimensions. `k1` and `k2` are in logarithmic scale, and `z` is in linear scale. Do the two-dimensional exponential functions serve the purpose? I read some of these post [stack posts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/178366/finding-surface-fit-on-3d-graph-that-have-different-data-length)  but, I did not understand much.

Comment: You'll need to get the data in shape by defining `data` and get `k1` and `k2` as logs.  One possibility:  `data = Flatten[Table[{Log[k1[[i]]], Log[k1[[j]]], z1[[i, j]]}, {i, 30}, {j, 30}], 1]; ListPointPlot3D[data]`.  The suface that can be envisioned from a plot of the points shows essentially no deviations from a smooth well-defined surface.  So doesn't the process that generated the data give a hint as to the functional form of the surface?

Comment: I guess I'm just a very skeptical person.  The `Min` and `Max` of the `z` values are awfully close to $\pi$ and $3\pi$.  Some function must have generated the data points rather than any measured data.

Comment: As you said it is close to pi and 3*pi, But I am obtaining it from my finite element calculations. So it no generated using any equations.